# Tortoise SVN: How to visually discern non-head files?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, explorer

Subversion in combination with TortoiseSVN: Quite often, I have to checkout some of my files at a previous revision, i. e. not the head revision. Sometimes single files, sometimes whole directories.
In Windows explorer, there is  no way to visually discern these files. This is a dangerous situation, since it is easy to forget which files are at what revision. Then, after some happy coding, I cannot check in these files, since they are at a previous revision. Which is corrent, it was me who did the error in the first place.

Is there a way so that it is easier for me to recognize these files? Something like displaying the revision of each file next to the file name (an option, which sadly does not exist)?